# If complex number $a, b, c, d,$ and $|a|=|b|=|c|=|d|=1$, why $|a(c+d)|+|b(c-d)|\leq 2\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math

If we have 4 complex number $a, b, c, d,$ and $|a|=|b|=|c|=|d|=1$, So, how to prove that $|a(c+d)|+|b(c-d)|\leq 2\sqrt{2}$？

I try to separate $|a(c+d)|+|b(c-d)|$ to $|a||(c+d)|+|b||(c-d)|$ than I get       $|(c+d)|+|(c-d)|$. SO, if $c=d, c+d=2c=2b, c-d=0$

Is my idea good?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Lee Alex  I solved your problem by C-S. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg How can I see the solution?

Comment: @Lee Alex   Very easy! Show your attempts and you'll see a solution immediately.

Comment: @Lee Alex Your first step was useful. The rest I posted.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ play no role in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c=\operatorname{cis}\alpha$ and $d=\operatorname{cis}\beta$.

Thus, by C-S we obtain: $$|a(c+d)|+|b(c-d)|=|c+d|+|c-d|=\sqrt{2+2\cos(\alpha-\beta)}+\sqrt{2-2\cos(\alpha-\beta)}=$$
$$=2|\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}|+2|\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}|\leq2\sqrt{(1+1)\left(\cos^2\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}+\sin^2\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)}=2\sqrt2.$$

Comment: Thank you, man!

Comment: @Lee Alex  You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You correctly started with
$$
|a(c+d)|+|b(c-d)| = |c+d|+  |c-d| \, .
$$
How can we estimate that if $|c|=|d|=1$ is known? Here helps the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law):
$$
|c+d|^2+|c-d|^2 = 2|c|^2 + 2|d|^2 = 4 \, .
$$
It remains to show that
$$
 |c+d|+  |c-d| \le \sqrt2 \sqrt{|c+d|^2+|c-d|^2}
$$
and that is exactly the  [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: Thanks a lot！！！

Answer (score 0):

$$|a(c+d)| +|b(c-d)|=|a||c+d| +|b||c-d|=|c+d| +|c-d|=\sqrt{(\cos \alpha +\cos \phi )^2 +(\sin\alpha +\sin\phi )^2 } +\sqrt{(\cos \alpha -\cos \phi )^2 +(\sin\alpha -\sin\phi )^2 }=\sqrt{2+ 2\cos \alpha \cos\phi +2\sin\alpha \sin \phi} +\sqrt{2- 2\cos \alpha \cos\phi -2\sin\alpha \sin \phi} =\sqrt{2+2\cos (\alpha -\phi )}+\sqrt{2-2\cos (\alpha -\phi )}=2\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos (\alpha -\phi )}{2}}+2\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos (\alpha -\phi )}{2}}=2\sqrt{\cos^2 \left(\frac{\alpha -\phi }{2}\right)} +2\sqrt{\sin^2 \left(\frac{\alpha -\phi }{2}\right)}=2\left(\left|\cos \left(\frac{\alpha -\phi }{2}\right)\right|+\left|\sin \left(\frac{\alpha -\phi }{2}\right)\right|\right)\leq 2 \sqrt{1^2 +1^2 }\sqrt{\left|\cos \left(\frac{\alpha -\phi }{2}\right)\right|^2+\left|\sin \left(\frac{\alpha -\phi }{2}\right)\right|^2} =2\sqrt{2}$$

where $c=\cos \alpha +i \sin\alpha , d=\cos\phi +i \sin \phi .$

Answer (score 0):

$$|a(c+d)|+|b(c-d)|=\left|1+\dfrac dc\right|+\left|1-\dfrac dc\right|=|1+e^{i\theta}|+|1-e^{i\theta}|$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $c$ and $d$.

Now

$$1+e^{i\theta}=2\cos^2\frac\theta2+2i\sin\frac\theta2\cos\frac\theta2=2\cos\frac\theta2 e^{i\theta/2}$$
and
$$1-e^{i\theta}=2\sin^2\frac\theta2-2i\sin\frac\theta2\cos\frac\theta2=2\sin\frac\theta2e^{-i\theta/2}.$$

Finally, the maximum of $\left|2\cos\dfrac\theta2\right|+\left|2\sin\dfrac\theta2\right|$ is $2\sqrt2$.